# How can I make textbox not editable when I click out of it?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a TreeView inside which are TextBoxes.
It looks like this:
I am trying to achieve:

- When I click on the other checkbox is should lose focus
- When I click out of the already edited checkbox it should lose focus, not staying editable.

I can achieve similar to that by pressing Enter or Tab key(or any other key).

```cs
private void OnModuleNameEditKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Tab)c
    {
        ModuleName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ModuleNameEdit.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing it?
Functionality is when I double click on TextBox it becomes editable but I want, when clicking out of range of checkbox to not edit it until I double click on it again.

Comment: Without at least a partial XAML code with the layout of UI elements, it will be impossible to answer your question.
What are the elements ModuleName, ModuleNameEdit?
How are they related to IsReadOnly?
Why does changing IsReadOnly change the visualization of an item?

Comment: Why can't you do this via the LostFocus and DoubleClick events?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock how do I check when the textbox has lost focus(btw there is logical focus and keyboard focus I don't get it) so I can make its Visibility.Collapsed ?

Comment: In XAML for the TextBox type "LostFocus=" and it will prompt you to create a new event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Create static variable to store working node (UIElement/Textbox). And try to set this event when keyboard focus lost.

Static variable:

```
public static TextBox CurrentTextBox = null;
```

In mouse double click event:

```
{ 
  CurrentTextBox = sender as TextBox;
  CurrentTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
  CurrentTextBox.IsVisible = true;
}
```

In keyboard focus lost event:

```
{
  CurrentTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
  CurrentTextBox .IsVisible = false;
  CurrentTextBox = null;
}
```